# How to update table with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i have been trying to update the status of my table but i can figure it out why this aint working, it shows the error messege so the status does not update

```
     $uid = $_GET["uid"]; 

     $query=$db->query("UPDATE INTO users SET status = 0 WHERE uid = '$uid'");    
    if ($query){
     echo "ok";
}
    else 
    {
        echo "error.";
    }
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not `update into` it should be

```
UPDATE users SET status = 0 WHERE uid = '$uid'
```

Comment: OMG, thanks i was really sleepy thats why i couldnt see the obvious,

Comment: @AlexRiiosCardoza I guess its the time for you to go to bed now :)

Answer (score 2):

Your query must be you were mixing insert and update query

```
UPDATE users SET status = 0 WHERE uid = '$uid'
```

You need to learn the difference

[**UPDATE**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

[**INSERT**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html)

```
INSERT INTO table_name ( field1, field2,...fieldN )
VALUES ( value1, value2,...valueN );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `INTO`, it can't be i `UPDATE` query.

```
$query=$db->query("UPDATE users SET status = 0 WHERE uid = '$uid'");
```